# Frameless window with aero snap functionalities using .Net core 2 (or 3) and qml.net

Tags: c#, .net-core, qml

I'm developing a code with .Net Core 2.2 and launching a [qml.Net](https://github.com/qmlnet/qmlnet) window.

```
using System;
using Qml.Net;
using Qml.Net.Runtimes;

namespace TestQMLNet
{
    class Program
    {
        static int Main(string[] args)
        {


            RuntimeManager.DiscoverOrDownloadSuitableQtRuntime();

            using (var app = new QGuiApplication(args))
            {
                using (var engine = new QQmlApplicationEngine())
                {
                    engine.Load("main.qml");
                    return app.Exec();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

qml part:

```
ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    width: 640
    height: 680
    visible: true
    title: "Project Management"
}
```

I want to make the window frame-less and also implement the min/max/close buttons with aero snap functionalities with new window header style. I can do this in C++/Qt but now I'm using C# in .Net core and I want to do this in this environment.

Note that I can make it frameless easily by adding "flags: Qt.FramelessWindowHint | Qt.Window" to the qml part but I want to add aero snap functionalities too.

Comment: Consider editing your questio and adding the qml related part (that "main.qml")

Comment: Did you check the `SetAttribute` function on `app`? https://github.com/qmlnet/qmlnet/blob/c5eac9656993e41e2b17c698de758ac70b292bb5/src/net/Qml.Net/ApplicationAttribute.cs Here you can see which attributes you can set. Btw, Qml.net looks like a cool project!

Comment: @Amfasis Yes, not useful for aero snap functionalities.

Comment: @Amfasis Also I don't know how to use them!